# I try to create and SQL table that contains 10000 rows from random elements. It gives me an error

Tags: python, postgresql

I'm trying to create an SQL table, it runs by this (this is in and SQL file, what I call in the end of my code '1-fake-mentor-candidates.sql')

```
CREATE TABLE "mentor_candidates" (
    first_name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    last_name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    phone_number varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    email varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    city varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    level integer NOT NULL,
    birth_year integer NOT NULL
);
```

That's my class, that should create my table, but it gives me back an error message: 
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "fake-mentor-candidates.py", line 39, in

FakeMentors.write_sql_file('1-fake-mentor-candidates.sql')

File "fake-mentor-candidates.py", line 35, in write_sql_file
    + cls.level + ");"

AttributeError: type object 'FakeMentors' has no attribute 'first_name'

```
class FakeMentors:

first_name_to_pick = ['Attila', 'Prezmek', 'John', 'Tim', 'Matthew', 'Andy', 'Giancarlo']
last_name_to_pick = ['Monoczki', 'Szodoray', 'Ciacka', 'Carrey', 'Obama', 'Lebron', 'Hamilton', 'Fisichella']
city_to_pick = ['Budapest', 'Miskolc', 'Krakow', 'Barcelona', 'New York']
phonenumber_to_pick = ['30', '20', '70']

def __init__(self):
    self.first_name = random.choice(self.first_name_to_pick)
    self.last_name = random.choice(self.last_name_to_pick)
    self.birth_year = random.randint(1960, 1995)
    self.email = self.first_name + self.last_name + str(random.randint(1, 100)) + '@codecool.com'
    self.city = random.choice(self.city_to_pick)
    self.phone_number = '+36' + self.random.choice(phonenumber_to_pick) + str(random. randint(100000, 999999))
    self.level = random.randint(1, 10)


@classmethod
def write_sql_file(cls, sql_file):
    with open(sql_file, 'w') as my_file:
        my_file.write('TRUNCATE TABLE  mentor_candidates;\nBEGIN TRANSACTION;\n')
        for row in range(0, 10000):
            sql_line = "INSERT INTO \"mentor_candidates\" "\
                       + "(first_name,last_name,birth_year,email,city,phone_number,level) "\
                       + "VALUES"\
                       + "(\'" + cls.first_name + "\',"\
                       + "\'" + cls.last_name + "\',"\
                       + cls.birth_year + ","\
                       + "\'" + cls.email + "\',"\
                       + "\'" + cls.city + "\',"\
                       + "\'" + cls.phone_number + "\',"\
                       + cls.level + ");"
            my_file.write(line + '\n')
        my_file.write("END TRANSACTION;\n")

FakeMentors.write_sql_file('1-fake-mentor-candidates.sql')
```

What am I doing wrong here? :/

Comment: I did! It is in the tagline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tried to access instance attributes in a classmethod. You need to create instances:

```
class FakeMentors:
    first_name_to_pick = ['Attila', 'Prezmek', 'John', 'Tim', 'Matthew', 'Andy', 'Giancarlo']
    last_name_to_pick = ['Monoczki', 'Szodoray', 'Ciacka', 'Carrey', 'Obama', 'Lebron', 'Hamilton', 'Fisichella']
    city_to_pick = ['Budapest', 'Miskolc', 'Krakow', 'Barcelona', 'New York']
    phonenumber_to_pick = ['30', '20', '70']

    def __init__(self):
        self.first_name = random.choice(self.first_name_to_pick)
        self.last_name = random.choice(self.last_name_to_pick)
        self.birth_year = random.randint(1960, 1995)
        self.email = self.first_name + self.last_name + str(random.randint(1, 100)) + '@codecool.com'
        self.city = random.choice(self.city_to_pick)
        self.phone_number = '+36' + self.random.choice(phonenumber_to_pick) + str(random. randint(100000, 999999))
        self.level = random.randint(1, 10)

    @classmethod
    def write_sql_file(cls, sql_file):
        with open(sql_file, 'w') as my_file:
            my_file.write('TRUNCATE TABLE  mentor_candidates;\nBEGIN TRANSACTION;\n')
            for row in range(0, 10000):
                entry = cls()
                my_file.write(('INSERT INTO "mentor_candidates" '
                        + "(first_name,last_name,birth_year,email,city,phone_number,level) "
                        + "VALUES"
                        + "('{0.first_name}', '{0.last_name}', {0.birth_year},"
                        + "'{0.email}','{0.city}','{0}.phone_number}',{0.level});\n").format(entry))
            my_file.write("END TRANSACTION;\n")

FakeMentors.write_sql_file('1-fake-mentor-candidates.sql')
```